# React: how to display success message if all requests were successful in a loop

Tags: reactjs, ajax, async-await, axios

I have an array of items. I am iterating over all items and making a post request to create a record in the db with axios. I want to show a success message if all requests were successful. Not sure how to do it?

I'm thinking of creating an array and pushing `true` and `false` to it. if the array values do not include `false`, then all requests were successful.

Any suggestion?

```
const handleAddTaskBacklogs = () => {
  setSubmitting(true);
  openSnackbar('Adding to task backlogs...');

  try {
    selectedBacklogs.forEach(async (backlog) => {
      await createResource.mutateAsync({
        url: taskBacklogsUrls.list(),
        values: {
          task: taskId,
          backlog,
        },
      });
    });

    openSnackbar('Backlog(s) added to the task');
    refetchTaskBacklogs();
    setActiveBacklog(null);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err.message);
    console.log(err.response && err.response.data);
    openSnackbar('Failed to add backlog(s) to the task');
  } finally {
    setSubmitting(false);
  }
};
```

Comment: Why not push all array values in a single request instead of multiple?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could map the `selectedBacklogs` to an array of Promises and [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) them.

> The `Promise.all()` method takes an iterable of promises as an input,
> and returns a single Promise that resolves to an array of the results
> of the input promises. This returned promise will resolve when all of
> the input's promises have resolved, or if the input iterable contains
> no promises. It rejects immediately upon any of the input promises
> rejecting or non-promises throwing an error, and will reject with this
> first rejection message / error.

```
const handleAddTaskBacklogs = async () => {
  setSubmitting(true);
  openSnackbar('Adding to task backlogs...');

  try {
    const promises = selectedBacklogs.map((backlog) => {
      return createResource.mutateAsync({
        url: taskBacklogsUrls.list(),
        values: {
          task: taskId,
          backlog,
        },
      });
    });

    const result = await Promise.all(promises);

    // all successful

    openSnackbar('Backlog(s) added to the task');
    refetchTaskBacklogs();
    setActiveBacklog(null);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err.message);
    console.log(err.response && err.response.data);
    openSnackbar('Failed to add backlog(s) to the task');
  } finally {
    setSubmitting(false);
  }
};
```

`Promise.all` will immediately reject at the first rejection. If you still need to process all the asynchronous POST requests then you may use [Promise.allSettled](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled). You can then check the `status` of each to see which were fulfilled successfully.

```
const result = await Promise.allSettled(promises);
const allFulfilled = result.every(({ status }) => status === 'fulfilled');

if (allFulfilled) {
  // all successful
}
```

Comment: thanks! will use `Promise.allSettled()` then

Comment: @DrewReese Won't the Promise.all be rejected if any of the promise fails? From MDN, _"It rejects immediately upon any of the input promises rejecting or non-promises throwing an error, and will reject with this first rejection message / error."_

Comment: @RobLjm Yes, but if they all succeed and resolve, that's all OP was asking for. If any of them reject ***and*** OP still wants the others to at least settle, then that's where the last part of my answer comes in.

Comment: @DrewReese Oh Yes. I didn't see the edit. My bad. Upvoted.